# Local Storage value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-storage

Value is not set in local storage.

```
const todo = () => {
    let value = document.querySelector("#input_box").value;
    let ok_btn = document.querySelector(".ok_btn");
    function main(){
        return localStorage.setItem("0", value);
    }
    ok_btn.addEventListener("click", main);   
}

todo();
```

I make a to-do function. This function is work properly but the local storage value is not set.

Comment: Why do you have `return` inside your `function main`? The `localStorage.setItem` method does not return anything...

Comment: 1. Your `let value` has set value on page load, not when your `main` is called. 2. You never read back from local storage

Comment: not sure why you think it's a good idea, but using "0" as your key is a horrible idea. Just like using null as a key would not be recommended. You are breaking all kinds of good coding practices. Maybe choose a more descriptive key name?

Comment: Also, " localstorage value is not set" is not true. It may not be set to what you want, but... [demo](https://jsbin.com/qedibilexe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: what is the purpose of wrapping your code in a function called "main"?

Comment: you have to click on "ok_btn" to trigger "main" function. Local storage value is not being set since, the button is never clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple problems with this code,

1. Not sure why you have a function (main) in the middle of your block of code. what is the purpose?
2. why do you have a return statement in the middle of your block?
3. I wouldn't use "0" as a key.

but maybe try something like this:

```
const todo = () => {
   let value = document.querySelector("#input_box").value;
   let ok_btn = document.querySelector(".ok_btn");
   localStorage.setItem("item0", value);
   ok_btn.addEventListener("click", main);   
}

todo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "0" as a key but it's not a good idea

```js
const todo = () => {
   let value document.querySelector("#input_box").value;
   let ok_btn = document.querySelector(".ok_btn");
   localStorage.setItem('0', value);
   ok_btn.addEventListener("click", main);   
}
```